# Webworker in angular 4 (@angular/platform-webworker)

Tags: angular, web-worker

I am following 2 references to create an application using web worker.
https://blog.angularindepth.com/angular-with-web-workers-step-by-step-dc11d5872135

but getting this error can someone help me

```
ERROR in ./src/main.ts
Module build failed: F:\learning 2017\angularcli\angular-cli-master\angular-cli-master\packages\@ngtools\webpack\src\index.ts:2
import { satisfies } from 'semver';
^^^^^^
SyntaxError: Unexpected token import
    at Object.exports.runInThisContext (vm.js:76:16)
    at Module._compile (module.js:542:28)
    at Object.Module._extensions..js (module.js:579:10)
    at Module.load (module.js:487:32)
    at tryModuleLoad (module.js:446:12)
    at Function.Module._load (module.js:438:3)
    at Module.require (module.js:497:17)
    at require (internal/module.js:20:19)
    at loadLoader (F:\learning 2017\app\learning\webworker\ngwebworker\node_modules\loader-runner\lib\loadLoader.js:13:17)
    at iteratePitchingLoaders (F:\learning 2017\app\learning\webworker\ngwebworker\node_modules\loader-runner\lib\LoaderRunner.js:169:2)
    at runLoaders (F:\learning 2017\app\learning\webworker\ngwebworker\node_modules\loader-runner\lib\LoaderRunner.js:362:2)
    at NormalModule.doBuild (F:\learning 2017\app\learning\webworker\ngwebworker\node_modules\webpack\lib\NormalModule.js:182:3)
    at NormalModule.build (F:\learning 2017\app\learning\webworker\ngwebworker\node_modules\webpack\lib\NormalModule.js:275:15)
    at Compilation.buildModule (F:\learning 2017\app\learning\webworker\ngwebworker\node_modules\webpack\lib\Compilation.js:151:10)
    at factoryCallback (F:\learning 2017\app\learning\webworker\ngwebworker\node_modules\webpack\lib\Compilation.js:344:12)
    at factory (F:\learning 2017\app\learning\webworker\ngwebworker\node_modules\webpack\lib\NormalModuleFactory.js:241:5)
 @ multi (webpack)-dev-server/client?http://localhost:4200 ./src/main.ts

ERROR in ./src/polyfills.ts
Module build failed: F:\learning 2017\angularcli\angular-cli-master\angular-cli-master\packages\@ngtools\webpack\src\index.ts:2
import { satisfies } from 'semver';
^^^^^^
SyntaxError: Unexpected token import
    at Object.exports.runInThisContext (vm.js:76:16)
```